# Clear an absolutely positioned sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stop my sidebars from leaking into the footer area and I've tried lots of suggestions none of which seems to work.

I'd consider JavaScript if need be, but would rather use CSS.  [Here's an example page](http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/news.html), I wondered if you check with a code inspector?  The left & right nav are positioned absolutely for the background image to reach the end above the footer, and the contents are floated.

I want the contents to be able to expand without running into the footer.

I just can't figure out how and no-one else seems to either so this is a last try!

Comment: You cannot clear an absolutely positioned element with css. What are the browser requirements (old IE versions...)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeroen said in his comment. Change `<div id="left-container">`, `<div id="right-container">` and `<div id="middle">` to `float:left` & `position:relative`. If you do this you will need to change the order to `<div id="left-container">` then `<div id="middle">` then `<div id="right-container">`. Some box model tweaking may be needed but your footer should now clear those elements. I almost forgot to mention to remove the margins on the `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you only need the absolute positioning of the side-bars because of the shadow on the middle box.

For older browsers I would make `#middle` wider to include the background and give `.inside` the necessary margins to separate it from `#middle` (and to give it one of the backgrounds).

For modern browsers I would just use a box shadow.

Of course all in combination with just floats, no absolute positioning.